# TextToSpeech is null in onPauseFragment

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

I have ViewPager with fragments, there is TextToSpeech in each of them. 
When I start tts and scroll to next fragment it keeps work because in fragment doesn't call any of lifecycle methods and i set up setOffscreenPageLimit = 3 this limit.
after i implemented service

```
public void onPageSelected(int pos) {FragmentLifecycle fragmentToHide =       (FragmentLifecycle)adapter.getItem(currentPosition);
fragmentToHide.onPauseFragment();    currentPosition = pos;
}
```

it calls method which I need but tts always is null, even if I hear it speaks

```
@Override public void onPauseFragment() {    if (tts != null) {
        tts.stop();
        tts.shutdown();
    }    }
```

please help me how to decide this problem.

Comment: From those code snippets alone it's not clear how you are using the TTS engine. If you have a separate `TextToSpeech` instance in each `Fragment` and if you all the time keep shutting them down and restarting them whenever scrolling the `ViewPager` then that's probably the wrong way to go and you could for example keep just one `TextToSpeech` instance in your `Activity` instead and always use that. Then call `tts.shutdown()` when your `Activity` is destroyed.

Comment: I create new TextToSpeech object in each fragment in onCreate method.

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        tts = new TextToSpeech(getActivity(), this);
    }

Comment: I'm trying to initialize in activity TextToSpeech, and I'm not sure how correctly to get it in my fragments

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        TextToSpeech tts = ((LogsPagerActivity)getActivity()).getTts();
}
Like this one?